# subida de archivos en un php

Tags: php

mi problema es el siguiente: 
 yo tengo un formulario en el cual al final hay una opción para subir archivos. 
He creado un php en XAMPP (procesainfocfile) para que se pueda subir bien pero en internet al intentar ejecutarlo me sale esto: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los php son estos : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien me puede ayudar para saber que tengo que cambiar por favor?

Comment: Hola, pon el codigo en texto no en imagenes por favor.

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="procesainfocfile.php" method="post" >   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value ="100000"> <input type="file" name="archivo" > <input type="submit" value="Subir archivo"></form>
<?php    
echo $_FILES['archivo']['name'],"<br/>\n";
echo $_FILES['archivo']['size'],"<br/>\n";
echo $_FILES['archivo']['type'],"<br/>\n";
echo $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],"<br/>\n";
echo $_FILES['archivo']['error'],"<br/>\n";
$temporal= $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$fijo=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($temporal,$fijo);
?></body></html>

Comment: Esto seria lo que tengo en la otra practica, 
<form method="post"  action="http://localhost/procesainfocfile.php" target="_blank"> 
<!--
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/procesainfoc.php" target="_blank">
-->

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido(a),

```
if(isset(archivo)){ /*Todo tu código dentro de esto*/}´
```

espero te ayude!

Comment: Pero la tengo guardada en htdocs. Me explico, la practica 8 y la de procesainfocfile son mis dudas. Ambas están guardadas en el mismo sitio (htdocs)